# PreloadJS - Loading an image from a URL without file format

Tags: easeljs, preloadjs

I'm trying to use PreloadJS to load an image. I took the getting started code from http://www.createjs.com/getting-started so,

```
function loadImage() {
  var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue();
  preload.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileComplete);
  preload.loadFile("assets/preloadjs-bg-center.png");
}
function handleFileComplete(event) {
  document.body.appendChild(event.result);
}
```

Which works great, but changing the URL to a custom one doesn't play so nice:

```
  preload.loadFile("http://localhost:3000/URLthatReturnsAnImageWithoutFileType");
```

I'm unable to render the image. I'm guessing the `loadFile` function parses the file type in the provided URL string. Is there a way to tell PreloadJS the provided asset is indeed an image and render it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [LoadQueue's documentation](http://www.createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/classes/LoadQueue.html), the file type of an item is determined by it's file extension. If it doesn't have an extension, then you can pass in a type property:

```
      preload.loadFile({src:"hello", type:createjs.AbstractLoader.IMAGE});
```